# Goggle APIS com C# através de proxy

Tags: c#, google, proxy

Estou tentando conectar no Google drive através do Google.apis mas aqui no meu serviço tem proxy e quando vou tentar buscar a credencial ele dá erro pedindo autorização do proxy. (abriu browser acessou uma pagina ele pede senha, se fechar o browser e abrir de novo ele vai pedir de novo).
Já tentei colocar proxy no config mas não funciona. tanto que não consigo nem logar minha conta no Visual Studio ele pede e-mail e senha mas depois dá erro que autenticação no proxy é requerida.
Alguém já passou por isto? Tem alguma solução?
Já olheia vários casos no stackflow pt e en e nada resolveu.
Liberar no proxy não é uma opção infelizmente.

Segue treco do código que ocorre o erro. ocorre quando ele vai no GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync para conectar.
...

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                String FolderPath = @"D:\";
                String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "DriveServiceCredentials.json");
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;
            }
```

Comment: e os logs do proxy ?

Comment: Não tenho acesso aos logs.

Comment: mas se mesmo estiver autenticado no proxy, e ele estiver bloqueando, não vai funcionar...

Comment: Achei uma solução. Usei essa solução: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rido/2010/05/06/how-to-connect-to-tfs-through-authenticated-web-proxy/
Criei a DLL coloquei no projeto e configurei o web.config para usar a dll.
O problema é que tem que manter usuário e senha do proxy no arquivo.